# Best practice for passing param Riverpod's providers only once

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I just want to build a `Provider` which asks params only one and inits correctly.

- Since I am just passing params only once, I don't prefer to use `.family` methods.
- I prefer to use `.autoDispose` which considered the better way.

Here my tryouts:

- I tried to make my own `.init()` method. But it's disposing as soon as method called if it's `.autodispose()` and the widget not started to listen my provider yet (that's expected). Therefore I couldn't consider a safe way to do that.
- I tried `.overrideWith()` method in a widget basis. But it's neither worked nor I am sure that it's best practice.

Here is my simple code:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  final myString = 'Hey';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    //Not worked
    ProviderContainer(
        overrides: [messageProvider.overrideWith(() => ViewModel(myString))]);

    return Scaffold(
      body: ProviderScope(
        //Not worked either
        overrides: [messageProvider.overrideWith(() => ViewModel(myString))],
        child: Center(
          //I just didn't use .when to shorter code
          child: Text(ref.watch(messageProvider).value!.counter.toString()),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

```dart
final messageProvider = AsyncNotifierProvider.autoDispose<ViewModel, Model>(
    () => throw UnimplementedError());
```

```dart
class ViewModel extends AutoDisposeAsyncNotifier<Model> {
  final String param;

  ViewModel(this.param);

  @override
  FutureOr<Model> build() {
    //Make some fetch with param, (only once!)
    return Model(param.length);
  }
}
```

When I run that. It gives `UnimplementedError`

Waiting your suggestions & fixes. Thanks in advance!

Expected:
Works properly.

Comment: I'm not sure, can you give a try to remove autoDispose modifier of the messageProvider .

Comment: `class ViewModel extends AutoDisposeAsyncNotifier<Model> {` ... by the time you're writing stuff like this, you should be using the generator.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I am not used to use generator yet :)

Answer (score 0):

```dart
@riverpod
ViewModel myViewModel(MyViewModelRef ref, String param){
    return ViewModel(param);
}
```

This is `autoDispose` by default in Riverpod 2. If you don't want to auto dispose you can use `@Riverpod(keepalive:true)` instead of `@riverpod`

If you don't want to pass the param to the provider, you can eliminate it and hardcode the value to the `ViewModel`, but at that point, if there are no other dependencies, might as well make it a `public` `final` variable in some file, since it looks like this is a singleton that never changes so it is questionable what you'd achieve by making it a Riverpod provider.